# Hosted BackgroundService StopAsync not executing after await

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

Here is an example code for loop inside ExecuteAsync method of `MyWorker`class that inherits from `BackgroundService`

```
 protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {

            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested){

                // Do some work

                // Sleep for 1s
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }

            // Do some work after stopping token is canceled
            this.WorkThatNeverExecutes()
        }
```

The problem is that after stoppingToken is canceled, the method `WorkThatNeverExeuctes` is never executed.

After investigating source code of the `BackgroundService` I've noticed the following:
In its `StopAsync` method, it is waiting until either my own background service (its `exeutingTask`) is finished or `cancellationToken` of the background service is canceled(it will be after a short delay):

What is happening here I think is my `await Task.Delay` after the `stoppingToken` is canceled, makes the `executingTask` completed and the parent `BackgroundService` exits. **I would like to know a way around this** so my `ExecuteAsync` is executed completely before returning. Also a way that does not include not passing `stoppingToken` to my Delay method or something similar (which would work).

```
 // Inside BackgroundService.cs    
  public virtual async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Stop called without start
            if (_executingTask == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                // Signal cancellation to the executing method
                _stoppingCts.Cancel();
            }
            finally
            {
                // Wait until the task completes or the stop token triggers
                await Task.WhenAny(_executingTask, Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken));
            }

        }
```

Comment: Sure that no one down the code throws an exception if cancelleation occured (When for example someone uses ThrowIfCancellationRequested(), that don't needs to be you can also be Frameworkcode). So catching OperationCanceledException additionally could help.

Comment: Did you try to return the `Task` returned from `ExecuteAsync` from `StopAsync`?

Comment: @Ralf no one throws exception because when I use Task.Delay(1000) instead of Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken) the code after while loop executes

Comment: @mm8 StopAsync method is inside BackgroundService.cs Task which is part of the aspnet framework so if I'd like to use it there is no way to change its behaviour, other then overiding which I'm trying to avoid

Comment: @user1480742:  `StopAsync` is called when the host is shutdown. Why would it wait for `ExecuteAsync` unless you implement it to?

Comment: Have you considered that Task.Delay itself throws an exception when the given token given to the method gets cancelled?

Comment: @user1480742 well the StopAsync method suggests that it waits for my task (executingTask) to return, what I'm not gettings is why wouldnt I finish my code (in some reasonable time , as a cleanup) before returning task

Comment: @Ralf you're right! I didn't notice the exception was thrown by Delay. Thanks!
As I see it can be avoided by wraping the code inside Task.WhenAny() or something similar so my code executes to the end..
If you want you can provide a suggested answer so I can accept it

Comment: I think that the code template used by Visual Studio when creating a WorkerService project should include the try-catch, I also couldn't figure why my code following the while() wasn't running.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as the @Ralf suggested the problem is that Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken) throws
**TaskCanceledException** so my code does not continue. The solution is to catch given exception and the convinient one liner is to wrap my Task.Delay into Task.WhenAny like this
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{

```
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested){

            // Do some work

            // Sleep for 1s
            await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken));
        }

        // Do some work after stopping token is canceled
        this.ThisWillExecuteAfterStoppingTokenIsCanceled()
    }
```